# How to calculate non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: riemann-zeta

I wanted to know how riemann calculated some non-trivial zero of the zeta function. Would I like a manual calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harold M. Edwards book 'Riemann's Zeta Function' covers Riemann's work on the zeta function in depth.

To answer your question, try:

[Riemann Zeta Function, p.5](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&pg=PA5&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false)

and Gram's  method:

[Riemann Zeta Function, p.96](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&pg=PA96&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

One can calculate nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ along the line $s=1/2+t \in \mathbb{C}$ using the algorithm below.

$\mathbf{Newton-Raphson}$ $\mathbf{Algorithm}$ $\mathbf{for}$ $\zeta(s)$:
Given an initial $t_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$, iterative solutions $t_{k+1}$ converge to nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$,

$t_{k+1}=t_{k}-\frac{2 i}{\frac{16 i t_{k}}{1+4t_{k}^2}+\log_{e}(\pi) - \frac{\Gamma'(1/4+i t_{k}/2)}{\Gamma(1/4+i t_{k}/2)}-\frac{2 \zeta’(1/2+i t_k)}{\zeta(1/2+i t_k)}}$.

Note that $t_k$ is the imaginary part of the root $s=1/2+i t_k$, with $\zeta(1/2+it_k)\approx 0$.